# Getting a specific value from an angular2 *ngFor array

Tags: angular

I have this cart component that I use for getting the cart data from the back end.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CartService } from './cart.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'cart',
    templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})

export class CartComponent implements OnInit{
    carts: any;
    cartItems: any;
    totalPrice: Number;

    constructor(private _cartService: CartService){};

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getItems();
    }

    getItems(){
        this._cartService.getCartItems(localStorage.getItem('currentUserId'))
            .subscribe((cart) => {
                this.cartItems = cart.products;
                this.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice;
                this.carts = cart;
                console.log(this.carts)
            },
            (err) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

This is my object values.

[image]

I put all the products inside cartItems as shown on my component and loop it in my template using *ngFor

```
<tbody *ngFor="let cartItem of cartItems">
```

This is the result

[image]

Now I want to update the quantity of one item, press the refresh button beside the remove button then it will send just the product details that I have the refresh button pressed to my back end.

Can someone help me on how to make it happen?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I need to get the object value from an array. for example the product Fast, i will update the quantity to 10, how can I get that from an *ngFor array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On click pass the cartItem in to the function called on click.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let cartItem of cartItems">
      <td>{{cartItem.product}}</td>
      <td>{{cartItem.size}}</td>
      <td>{{cartItem.price}}</td>
      <td>{{cartItem.quantity}}</td>
      <td>{{cartItem.subtotal}}</td>
      <td><button (click)="onClick($event, cartItem)">Refresh Button</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now, in the component class use the `cartItem`

```
onClick(event, cartItem){
   console.log(cartItem); // here your cart item object will be shown
   // do your stuff here with your cartItem
}
```

Comment: what is the $event for?

Comment: If you want to do anything with the target element, you can do it with it useng `event.target` in the function. Just added for future uses. But currently, it is nothing